# Document View Permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions, list-view, groups

Can I assign custom document views to groups and not have them see other documents in the library? I have created the views but can't figure out how to give permissions to them.

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box SharePoint does not have permissions on views.  If you want to have some users/groups see certain documents and not others you can assign permissions at the document level. The document library views will then only show the users what they have access to.